# why mask-image property is not working in browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I created a web page. When I opened the page with VScode editor's *Live Server extension* it is working as expected. But when I opened the same page normally with Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer it is looking horrible. Probably the mask-image property is not working correctly what is the alternative of mask-image. I already tried -webkit-mask-image.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cover">
            <div id="mobile_background"></div>
            <div id="page_background"></div>
            <div id="page_background2"></div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="round_image"></div>
                <div id="SIGN_IN"><u>SIGN IN</u></div>
                <form id="form_back">
                    <input type="text" id="text" class="round_edge"><br>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="round_edge"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="submit" class="round_edge">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS Code

```
#cover{
    position: relative;
}
#mobile_background{
    background-image: url("./MobileBorder.svg");
    height: 35em;
    width: 18em;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

#page_background{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(105, 115, 251),rgb(214, 114, 253));
    height: 31.5em;
    width: 18em;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:5em;
    margin-left: -100px;
    mask-image: url("./Layer 3.svg");
    /* background-color: black; */
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

#page_background2{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(105, 115, 251,0.1),rgba(226, 153, 255,0.3));
    height: 31.5em;
    width: 18em;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:2em;
    margin-left: -65px;
    mask-image: url("./Layer 3.svg");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("./Layer 3.svg");
    /* background-color: black; */
    mask-size: 100% 100%;
    /* background-color: black; */
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

#container{
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
    width: 15em;
    left:50%;
    top:50px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

#SIGN_IN{
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    top:6em;
    left: 50px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#round_image{
    background-image: url("./big3.png");
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:8em;
    left: 5em;
    border-radius: 30px;

}

#form_back{
    position: absolute;
    top:20em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.round_edge{
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: rgb(209, 174, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

With Live Server on the page in firefox
[image]

With normal firefox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`background-image: url("./big3.png");`

to

`background-image: url(big3.png);`

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is happening because browsers don't support **background-image:linear-gradient(...);** **and mask-image:URL()** together maybe....

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. All looks good in VSCode, but when I open the html file outside of VSCode, none of my masked images are displayed. If i use a "`background-image: url(../img/firework.png);`" I can see the image.

```
    .list-0 {
    mask-image: url(../img/firework.png);
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--color-five);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is CORS policy

The solution is simple.
Use this link to convert your svg image to base64.
https://codebeautify.org/svg-to-base64-converter

Use the base64 in the url of property mask-image and background-image.
Done.